# Why is my ReactiveExtensions msmq wrapper not continuing to listen?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, msmq

Can anyone identify why this listens to the MSMQ once, and then exits?  I thought that the `DoWhile()` would keep it listening, but when there are messages in the queue at startup, it processes them once and then exits.  Is there a more proper way to listen until `StopRequested`?

```
public virtual void RunProcessor()
{
    _stopRequested = false;
    MessageQueue mq = null;
    try
    {
        //create a subscribable stream from the msmq async BeginRecieve event
        mq = GetMessageQueue();
        var msmqListener =
            Observable.FromAsync(() => Task<Message>.Factory.FromAsync(mq.BeginReceive(), mq.EndReceive));
        Subscribe(msmqListener.DoWhile(() => !StopRequested));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if ((ex is ThreadAbortException) || (ex is ThreadInterruptedException)) throw;
        _logger.Error("Alert processor thread threw an exception", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        mq?.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like in previous versions of Reactive, the `finally` didn't get called until the `.DoWhile()` exited, as if there was an implicit `await`.  We got it working by taking the `mq?.Close()` out of the finally, but I'd still love to confirm that this is a reasonable implementation of a Reactive MSMQ.

Comment: Can you try changing `msmqListener` to `var msmqListener = Observable.Defer(() => Observable.FromAsync(() => Task<Message>.Factory.FromAsync(mq.BeginReceive(), mq.EndReceive)));` and see if that helps?

Comment: Also, can you please provide a [mcve]? It's really hard to test solutions when you don't provide all of the code.